# binary floating point addition algorithm

Tags: floating-point, binary, ieee-754

I'm trying to understand IEEE 754 floating point addition at a binary level. I have followed some example algorithms that I have found online, and a good number of test cases match against a proven software implementation. My algorithm is only dealing with positive numbers at the moment. However, I am not getting a match with this test case:

```
00001000111100110110010010011100 (1.46487e-33)
00000000000011000111111010000100 (1.14741e-39)
```

I split it up into sign bit, exponent, mantissa. I add back in the implicit 1 to the mantissa

```
0 00010001 1.11100110110010010011100
0 00000000 1.00011000111111010000100
```

I subtract the larger exponent from the smaller in order to determine the realignment-shift amount:

```
 00010001 (17)
-00000000 (0)
 =============
           17
```

I tack on a Guard bit, Round Bit, and Sticky Bit to the mantissas:

```
1.11100110110010010011100 000
1.00011000111111010000100 000
```

I shift the lesser value's mantissa to the right 17 times, with the LSb "sticking" once it receives a 1:

```
0.00000000000000001000110 001
```

I add the greater mantissa to the shifted lesser mantissa:

```
1.11100110110010010011100 000 +
0.00000000000000001000110 001
================================
1.11100110110010011100010 001
```

Since there was no overflow, and the guard bit is 0, I can use the summation-mantissa and greater-exponent directly (re-removing the implicit '1'):

```
0 00010001 11100110110010011100010
```

Giving a final value of:

```
00001000111100110110010011100010 (1.46487e-33)
```

But according to my verification implementation, I should be getting:

```
00001000111100110110010010101000 (1.46487e-33)
```

So very close but not exact. Is there a mistake in my algorithm?

Comment: Zero exponent means subnormal number. There is no implicit one bit.

Comment: The subnormal error accounts for a one bit difference in the final result, 00001000111100110110010010100010. It does not explain the different location of the least significant one bit in the two answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appear to be two problems in the calculation, both related to treating a subnormal number as though it were normal:

1. Incorrect shift calculation. The exponent is -126, not -127.
2. Incorrectly inserting a one bit before the binary point.

Here is the revised calculation:

```
0 00010001 1.11100110110010010011100
0 00000000 0.00011000111111010000100
```

Tack on a Guard bit, Round Bit, and Sticky Bit to the mantissas:

```
1.11100110110010010011100 000
0.00011000111111010000100 000
```

16 bit right shift of smaller number.

```
0.00000000000000000001100 001
```

Add the greater mantissa to the shifted lesser mantissa:

```
1.11100110110010010011100 000 +
0.00000000000000000001100 001
================================
1.11100110110010010101000 001
```

Comment: Curious why is the round bit 0 here?  I'd expect: "0.00000000000000000001100 0`1`1".